# Getting the username from LDAP - Can you tell me what's wrong?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'd like to ask you how can i dinamically get a username from ldap. As you can see below, i entered the username 'smith2'

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"] = 'smith2';
$param = $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]
```

And I can get his first name, like this:

```
$ldap1 = new ldapl;
$fname=$ldap1->getFname($param);
```

This is useful because I have some forms with some fields which are filled by default (name, first name, etc).

It must be dynamic. Each person has a PC, so the person Y should see his name, first name, etc The person X his name, first name, etc.

I deleted the line $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"] = 'smith2';
and i did like this:

```
$fname=$ldap1->getFname($_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]);
```

But it does not work, it displays anything. Can you tell me whats wrong?

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The variable $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] is probably empty.

You can check predefined variables using phpinfo();

See http://us.php.net/phpinfo

To fix this you need to replace the variable name with an accurate one that actually holds the value of the username you want to fetch LDAP information for.

You can also debug this by adding the following line below your code:

```
echo "REMOTE_USER: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']}";
```